# Why a single trajectory can be used to update the policy network $\theta$ in A3C?

Tags: policy-gradients, actor-critic-methods

The [Deep RL bootcamp on policy gradient techniques](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_gwYj1Q-44&list=PLAdk-EyP1ND8MqJEJnSvaoUShrAWYe51U&index=4) gives the update equation for the policy network in A3C as

$\theta_{i+1} = \theta_i + \alpha \times 1/m \sum_{k=1}^m\sum_{t=0}^{H-1}\nabla_{\theta}log\pi_{\theta_i}(u_t^{(k)} | s_t^{(k)})(Q(s_t^{(k)},u_t^{(k)}) - V_{\Phi_i}^\pi(s_t^{(k)}))    $

However in the [actual A3C paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01783), the gradient update is based on a single trajectory and there is no averaging of the gradient over $m$ trajectories as defined in the video ? The simple [action-value actor-critic algorithm](https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2018/04/08/policy-gradient-algorithms.html#a2c) also does not seem to require an averaging over m trajectory.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the gradient of the expectation of the Utility function, $\nabla_{\theta}J(\theta)$ in policy gradient methods where $\nabla_{\theta}J(\theta) = E_{\tau \sim p(\tau ; \theta)}[r(\tau)\nabla_{\theta}log p(\tau;\theta)]$ can be approximated using a single sample trajectory as shown in a [deep reinforcement learning lecture by stanford](https://www.youtube.com/watchv=lvoHnicueoE&list=RDCMUCdKG2JnvPu6mY1NDXYFfN0g&index=1) where $J(\theta) \approx \sum_{t > 0}r(\tau)\nabla_{\theta}log\pi_{\theta}(a_t |s_t)$ and an average over sampled trajectories is not needed to compute the gradient for $\theta$ update in the direction of gradient.